# Jelly bean guessing while loop?

Tags: java

I'm asked to implement a program that generates a random number of jelly beans in a jar, prompt the user to make a guess on how many jelly beans are in the jar, and count how many times the user tried to guess before getting it right.

That's my problem right there -- getting the program to count how many times the user inputted a guess. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class JellyBeanGame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numOfJellyBeans = 0;       //Number of jellybeans in jar
    int guess = 0;                       //The user's guess



     Random generator = new Random();
     Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    //randomly generate the number of jellybeans in jar
     numOfJellyBeans = generator.nextInt(999)+1;


    System.out.println("There are between 1 and 1000 jellybeans in the jar,");


do
{
    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");//prompt user to quess and read in 
    guess = scan.nextInt();

        if(guess < numOfJellyBeans) //if the quess is wrong display message
        {
            System.out.println("Too low.");
        }
        else if(guess > numOfJellyBeans);
        {
            System.out.println("Too High.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You got it");  // display message saying guess is correct
        }
}   while (guess != numOfJellyBeans);





}
```

}

Comment: You are just trying to keep track of the number of guesses? Just keep a variable for that, and increase it whenever scan.nextInt() returns.

Comment: @gamernb Yeah I am could you give me an example?

Comment: Agree with gamemb: add a variable like int guessCount=0. In the loop, say after you read in guess, have a guessCount++. Then you can change your display message to something like "You got it in " + guessCount + " guesses."

Comment: fvrghl's example is pretty close. I'd modify it slightly (see the comment below it).

Comment: You should go back through your previously asked questions and accept a few answers.  I see that you haven't accepted any yet.

Answer (score 2):

Have a counter variable that you increment on each loop in the while loop.  Something like this:

```
int num_guesses = 0;
do {
System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");//prompt user to quess and read in 
guess = scan.nextInt();
num_guesses++; // increment the number of guesses

    if(guess < numOfJellyBeans) //if the quess is wrong display message
    {
        System.out.println("Too low.");
    }
    else if(guess > numOfJellyBeans)
    {
        System.out.println("Too High.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You got it");  // display message saying guess is correct
        System.out.println("It took you " + num_guesses + " guesses!"); // display message with number of guesses
    }
}   while (guess != numOfJellyBeans);
```

Comment: You are saying that if they get it on the first try you are going to write "It took you 0 guesses!"? Just increment the var right after guess = scan.nextInt()

Comment: @gamernb Ha, I didn't think someone would be that lucky, but you are right.

Comment: @fvrghl I think I got it now! Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: @fvrghl do you know why the second else gives me a syntax error?

Comment: @AlexNuff You have a semicolon after the `else if`.  I didn't notice that when I pasted in your code (see edit)

Comment: @fvrghl oh okay and would I need to add after that second else (guess == numOfJellyBeans)? or do I leave it cause for some reason it's telling me to delete this token

Comment: @AlexNuff In java, you can't do `else (some statement)`.  `else` means **everything** else.  You don't need a statement anyways because the first two `if` statements take care of the cases when `guess != numOfJellyBeans`

Answer (score 1):

Before the `do` part, define a variable `int guessesCount = 0;` then just increment it after each `scan`: `guessesCount++;`

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial:

```
 int count = 0;

 // inside while loop
      count++;

 // outside while loop

 // do what you want with count
```

Comment: Even if you did - your answer has the quality a 3 year old child can give. +rep is all that matters, right?

Comment: Sure thing Jeff. It's not like he's trying to solve P=NP. It's the right answer, in its most simple form. Why over complicate things?